# C++ member function overloading picks wrong function

Tags: c++, overloading, member-functions

MSVC throws error C2660 when trying to overload a global function as a member function (with different number of arguments) that calls the global function in it's body.

This code:

```
void f(int* x, int y) { *x += y; }

struct A
{
    int* x;
    inline void f(int y)
    {
        f(x, y); // tries to call A::f instead of f
    }

    void u(void)
    {
        f(5);
    }
};
```

gives this error:

```
error C2660: 'A::f' : function does not take 2 arguments
```

Comment: Btw, in C++ you don't need `void` for functions with no arguments: `void u()` works too.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That's new to me, but I personally would still do it for completeness.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat /agree cybermonkey I never used `foo(void)` because of my C++ background - and now, while working in C, have that effing nasty habit of skipping it, resulting in constant compiler errors... FWIF, I'd advise him to keep `(void)`ing - it doesn't hurt any, and it certainly helps to have the habit IMO.

Comment: The compiler simply works as the standard say it should. It is up to you to learn rules...

Comment: @Phil1970 I don't care about the standard, what the compiler does is what matters, and not all compilers follow the intricate mess that is the C++ standard the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `::f(x, y);` to use the one in global namespace.

Comment: That worked, Thanks! (a little strange it can't figure it out considering there's not even the same number of arguments). This way it's more explicit so there's that.

Comment: @Marg the reason is that you're function isn't an overload and you don't get any kind of overload resolution, it's simply shadowing the global function with the same name.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl I see. Even though I compile with C++ I have mostly used it like C and only used features when I'e needed them.

Answer (score 6):

Unqualified name lookup on `f` will start at the narrowest scope and work its way outward. When we find `A::f`, we stop: we already found what we were looking for. We don't keep going. Moreover, since `A::f` is a class member, we don't even perform argument dependent lookup - we simply stop.

To call `::f`, you need to use a qualified call:

```
::f(x,y);
```

---

You might think that this problem might be solved with a *using-declaration*:

```
using ::f;
f(x,y);
```

This works in this case. However, we're still not overloading the two `f`s; any attempt to call the member function will fail for the same reason: `::f` will be found first and then we stop.